# Removing user object from Ad Group-Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, active-directory

How can i remove user objects from an AD Group and not delete user contacts? I do not want to delete contacts from the AD Group. I have a script but i feel it will delete contacts too

```
import-module activedirectory
$group="Group Name"
Get-ADGroupMember "$group" | ForEach-Object {Remove-ADGroupMember "$group" $_ -Confirm:$false}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter on the `objectclass` to pass only user objects.

```
Get-ADGroupMember $group |
    Where-Object {$_.objectclass -eq 'user'} |
    ForEach-Object {Remove-ADGroupMember $group $_ -Confirm:$false}
```